# Is synchronous XMLHttpRequest supported in Internet Explorer 10 and 11?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

I am having no luck trying to find an authoritative answer to this question, prompted by the claim at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) that IE 10 and 11 have dropped support for synchronous requests. See the Known Issues tab on this page:

http://www.caniuse.com/#search=xmlhttprequest

The only reference to any problems with synchronous XMLHttpRequest in IE 11 that I could find are two invalid bug reports:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/810738/ie-11-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-fails
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/801404/ie-11-still-does-not-support-xmlhttprequest-async-false

Could someone confirm that synchronous is supported in these versions? Up until today I treated [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) as authoritative, now I'm not so sure. I'll have to look into how they obtain their data.

Comment: why don't you try it and see??

Comment: I have no access to a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a happy coincidence I found [a link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) on the [jQuery Browser Support](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) page to Virtual Machines offered by Microsoft for testing of IE 10 and 11. I downloaded the IE11/Win7 file, and used it to confirm that synchronous XMLHttpRequest works just fine in this browser. I'll notify caniuse.com, so they can correct their mistake. I will invite them to comment here as to how that mistake could happen - it undermines trust in their platform.